# Copying two-dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

What should I do with a two-dimensional array if I want to copy each line of it and make it a new two-dimensional array?

Here is the format of this two-dimensional array:

```
{
  "localTrain": "T7",
  "TC": "2",
  "TimeSheet": [
    ["01", "London", "BXP", "T7", "1632", "1640"],
    ["02", "Shanghai", "QWE", "T7", "1200", "1240"],
    ["03", "LosAngeles", "DFG", "T7", "1300", "1340"],
    ["04", "NewDelhi", "VGH", "T7", "1400", "1440"],
    ["05", "Sydney", "SAW", "T7", "1500", "1540"],
    ["06", "Tokyo", "SAT", "T7", "1600", "1640"],
    ["07", "Seoul", "BBT", "T7", "1700", "1740"],
    ["08", "CapeTown", "OOP", "T7", "1800", "1840"],
  ]
}
```

And it should look like this:

```
{
  "localTrain": "T7",
  "TC": "2",
  "TimeSheet": [
    ["01", "London", "BXP", "T7", "1632", "1640"],
    ["01", "London", "BXP", "T7", "1632", "1640"],
    ["02", "Shanghai", "QWE", "T7", "1200", "1240"],
    ["02", "Shanghai", "QWE", "T7", "1200", "1240"],
    ["03", "LosAngeles", "DFG", "T7", "1300", "1340"],
    ["03", "LosAngeles", "DFG", "T7", "1300", "1340"],
    ["04", "NewDelhi", "VGH", "T7", "1400", "1440"],
    ["04", "NewDelhi", "VGH", "T7", "1400", "1440"],
    ["05", "Sydney", "SAW", "T7", "1500", "1540"],
    ["04", "NewDelhi", "VGH", "T7", "1400", "1440"],
    ["06", "Tokyo", "SAT", "T7", "1600", "1640"],
    ["06", "Tokyo", "SAT", "T7", "1600", "1640"],
    ["07", "Seoul", "BBT", "T7", "1700", "1740"],
    ["07", "Seoul", "BBT", "T7", "1700", "1740"],
    ["08", "CapeTown", "OOP", "T7", "1800", "1840"],
    ["08", "CapeTown", "OOP", "T7", "1800", "1840"],
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new object that is similar to the old object, except loop through each `TimeSheet` array element and push it onto the new object's `TimeSheet` array not once but twice.

```js
const oldObj = {
  "localTrain": "T7",
  "TC": "2",
  "TimeSheet": [
    ["01", "London", "BXP", "T7", "1632", "1640"],
    ["02", "Shanghai", "QWE", "T7", "1200", "1240"],
    ["03", "LosAngeles", "DFG", "T7", "1300", "1340"],
    ["04", "NewDelhi", "VGH", "T7", "1400", "1440"],
    ["05", "Sydney", "SAW", "T7", "1500", "1540"],
    ["06", "Tokyo", "SAT", "T7", "1600", "1640"],
    ["07", "Seoul", "BBT", "T7", "1700", "1740"],
    ["08", "CapeTown", "OOP", "T7", "1800", "1840"],
  ]
};

let newTimeSheet = [];
oldObj.TimeSheet.forEach(arrForOneCity => {
  newTimeSheet.push(arrForOneCity);
  newTimeSheet.push(arrForOneCity);
});

let newObj = {
  localTrain: oldObj.localTrain,
  TC: oldObj.TC,
  TimeSheet: newTimeSheet
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj));
```

Comment: You're very welcome. It looks like you are relatively new to Stack Overflow, so welcome aboard. Please note: If I help you by answering your question, you can help me in return by accepting my answer by clicking on the gray checkmark at the upper left of my answer. That indicates that you have "accepted" my answer and, in the process, gives me reputation points, which helps me. Even if you only check back here a long time into the future, that would really help me. In the mean time, all the best with your coding.

Comment: Your efforts to make Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange work the way they are supposed is much appreciated. All the best with your coding.